# What do "." and ".." mean when in a folder?

Tags: command-line

when I used `ls -a` to view hidden files in folder there were 2 hidden files created by default what is the significance of this two files `.` and `..`?

```
ls -a
```

Produces

```
.  ..
```

Comment: I use them a lot when I do an `ls -la` since it will show me the permissions and ownership on the directory I'm in and the directory above the one I'm in.

Comment: i don't have enough rep here to vote to close, but I've put a flag on this question as it's very much a question that can be answered in 3 seconds by searching google (and because there was a recent discussion about questions that are *too* easy on SO blog).

Comment: ^zzzzBov Thank you in Spanish for your generosity.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`.` is the current folder.

`..` is the folder above the current folder - the folder that contains the current folder.

You will sometimes see that single dot in use when someone wants to run a script from their home directory. For instance: `./install-app.sh`. That means the `install-app.sh` file is in the *current directory*. It would be just as valid to do `/home/username/directory/install-app.sh`. The same way, you could also do `../install.app` if the file is in the *parent directory*. The reason it's this way is not only for navigation, but also that it shouldn't be possible to accidentally hide system applications simply by misnaming a file in your home directory.

Comment: 100% correct. Think of them as hooks, that are in every single directory.  They are used purely for navigation.  You will find that this isn't just a linux standard, but on windows as well.  Probably the same on unix and mac as well, but i've never played around in either of their command prompts.

Comment: `cd / ; cd ..` :P

Comment: It's the same on FreeBSD too, so I imagine it is also that way on mac, since mac is based on Darwin BSD.

Comment: htorque: are you a religious person perhaps? :)

Comment: It's on Mac OS X (which works just like any other Unix, though the GUI hides some of it). Mac OS Classic did not have them; `::` was used for previous directory. Paths without `:` in them were current directory. Otherwise, a full path (starting with disk name) was expected, with components delimited by `:`. Ex: `Macintosh HD:System Folder:Finder`

Comment: @htorque yeah `/` is in `/` is in `/` ... See `cd ///////////////////// ; pwd`

Comment: Though that's due to bash ignoring multiple slashes, e.g. `cd /etc/////////init` works too.

Answer (score 5):

Those are hardlinks to self (.) and parent (..) directories. They are created when you crate a directory. They can never be deleted (without deleting directory pointed by them).

If you create a directory:

```
mkdir /tmp/foo
```

you can see, that there are actually 2 hardlink to /tmp/foo:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 michal michal 4096 2011-08-07 18:40 /tmp/foo
           ^---- two hardlinks
```

first is from /tmp/ directory pointing to /tmp/foo, and the second is the '.' with in /tmp/foo/ pointing to it self.

Answer (score 3):

Also, note that you can use `ls -A` (instead of `ls -a`) to list all files including hidden files, but excluding the `.` and `..` directories.

Answer (score 0):

`.` currect folder

`..` parent folder