# [Error]Failed to read password file: open ~/RPI/filename.sec: no such file or directory. But it exist

Tags: command-line, powershell

Trying to run .sh file. with --password "~/RPI.filename"in it. Should read the filename but getting an error. Even though the file exists

error:

```
Fatal: Failed to read password file: open ~/RPI/filename.sec: no such file or directory
```

list of directories and files:

```
~/RPI$ l
g.json  m1/  m2/  filename.sec  startm1.sh
```

It's not like I have never done this. I have used this exact method many times before but never ran into this issue. I have tried to redo the whole thing but still nothing

Comment: Did you actually place quotes around the filename (`"~/RPI.filename"` rather than `~/RPI.filename`)? That will prevent the shell from treating `~` specially. See for example [Why isn't tilde recognised as home folder in this case?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192981/why-isnt-tilde-recognised-as-home-folder-in-this-case)

Comment: Yes my .sh file contains '--password "~/RPI/filename.sec"' word to word.

Comment: just changed the filename to match the question to avoid confusion

Comment: @steeldriver actually it was the opposite. Just tested it by removing quotation marks and it worked